# Story of Vincent in Collateral (2004 film)

Tags: plot-explanation, character, collateral

I just watched the movie Collateral. I understand about everyone's role in the movie but I don't know what motivates Vincent to kill the 5 people. What is/are the reason(s) behind this? Is there any information regarding contracts on other people (that are killed) or the person that gave the contract to Vincent? Is Vincent killing people because he wants the world to notice him?

Comment: Well, he's a contract killer and that's just his job (/nature?). As much as I would love some elabortation on this character from one of *Mann*'s best movies, I'd dare to say this would be entirely speculation, as the lack of iformation on his motivation (or lack thereof in the first place) seems to a large degree intentional. But well, let's wait for some hopefully great answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vincent is a contract killer; he is killing them because he's paid to. He was hired by *"drug lord Felix Reyes-Torrena"*, as the [Wikipedia synopsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collateral_(film)#Plot) explains:

> FBI special agent Frank Pedrosa... identifies the targets as witnesses in a federal grand jury indicting Felix tomorrow. In retaliation, Felix has hired Vincent to kill all five key witnesses.

Vincent is hoping that the world *doesn't* notice him, hence the (previously-successful) attempt to pin the murders on his cab driver.

Comment: So is the motivation behind killing is that world is not noticing him ? like he told `Max` in taxi that world is not noticing them

Comment: @AHF Vincent **doesn't want** the world to notice him - he's a hitman, and (presumably) would rather not go to prison. The plan is that he comes to town, kills the five targets, kills and frames Max and disappears again to count the money.